# Access to a field of a Embedded class from CrudRepository SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this:

```
@Embeddable ClassA{
   private String attributeA;
   private String attributeB;
}

@Entity ClassB{
   private String attributeC;
   @Embedded ClassA extraAttrs;

}
```

Finally I have a CrudRepository from I want to get a query by using an attribute of ClassA, so I can't write this for example:

```
public interface TestCrud extends CrudRepository<ClassB, Long> {    
    public List<ClassB> findByAttributeA(String anA);
}
```

I can't do because attribute A is in the embedded ClassA instead off ClassB

How can I access from the CrudRepository interface definition to this attribute? Because this data it's in a single table, the purpose to put in a Embedded class it's because the attributes of ClassA are common to a lot of entitys, but not the PK, but now I need to access as I've said before.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot to everyone who try to help me :),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very simple, you need to concat them together, in your case try this

```
findByExtraAttrsAttributeA(...)
```

Comment: It works!! it's just what i was looking for

Thanks a lot!!